# How do I write a loop around my "if" tests?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and am trying to make a program for my 5-year old son. I want to ask him how to spell a word in his spelling list (in person, not on the screen) and he types it into Ruby and, if the answer is correct, then it puts 'Well done!' and re-runs. If it's incorrect then it puts 'Try again!' and re-runs.

Here is what I have come up with for one word:

```
puts 'How do you spell?..'
spell = gets.chomp
if spell =='disappointed' 
puts 'Well Done!'
elsif spell != 'disappointed'
 puts 'try again!'
end
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get it to re-run?  Whether right or wrong, do I need to set up a loop? If so, what's the easiest way to make it go back to the start so that he can answer without re-running. Obviously not putting `end` would be a start, but I get a message 'unexpected $end, expecting kEND'.
2. If I want to add in more words, what is the best way?

   ```
   if spell =='disappointed' || 'knowledge'  (etc)
   puts 'Well Done!'  
   elsif spell != 'disappointed'|| 'knowledge'   (etc)
     puts 'try again!'
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For easy updating, I'd recommend putting the correct words in an array:

```
words = %w{disappointed knowledge}
```

You can put the words on separate lines, too, if you have lots of words.

You can then check if the word entered is in the list:

```
if words.include? spell
    # ...
else
    # ...
end
```

Note that I've used `else` rather than `elsif` — `else` covers every possible other condition, which is what you want. `elsif` works too, but why repeat a condition when not necessary?

As for doing it multiple times, use `loop`:

```
loop do
    # ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you, thats great!  Can you advise why this didn't work? 
 words = %w{disappointed knowledge}

 loop do
 
 puts "How do you spell..."
 
 words = gets.chomp
 
 if words.include? spell
 
 puts 'Well Done!'
 
 else
 
  puts 'Try again!'
 
 end

Comment: @Jason: You have an `end` for the `if`, but no `end` for the `loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at while loop in ruby.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/part_02/while.html

Comment: Thanks Hrishi, I know a little about loops, so I'm guessing I put the loop before and after the 'program' I wrote?

Comment: yeah. it is basically                                            `code`                                                               while true                                                           <statements which have to be repeated go here>                           end                                                              `code`